# Why is postgres UPDATE function so slow?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table with about 180K records defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE table( 
    id text UNIQUE,
    classification text,
    author text,
    date DATE,
    score float,
    transcript text
    )
```

Nothing here is too remarkable except for one thing. All text values are < 200 characters, except for the transcript column. The text in the transcript column oftentimes ends up at hundreds of characters, up to 3MB of data. That being said, when I run the following command in the pipeline where I'm setting new classifications:

```
conn = connect()
conn.cursor().execute("UPDATE table SET classification = '%s' WHERE author = '%s'" % (classification, author))
```

The command takes an extraordinary amount of time. I've waited +30 minutes and I've yet to see this command finish. Furthermore, it locks these rows for this time which freezes up an attached webapp that queries the table. I can't quite understand why this is taking so long.

Lastly, of note, each author has fewer than 40 entries in the table. So the "WHERE" condition should never affect more than that many entries.

Comment: The lack of an index will lead to a sequential scan, but with a small table like that this should be quite fast. The only explanation is that the update is blocked by a lock. Use the `pg_blocking_pids` function on the process ID of the hanging backend process.

Comment: What exactly is the WebApp waiting for? If it’s just reading from your table then it should not be effected by locks. Also, you should be using bind variables rather than just string formatting for any inputs - this is a classic SQL injection entry point.

Comment: In addition to what has been said: 1) Have you looked at the Postgres log to see if it has anything useful? 2) Are `sector_long, ticker` really the variables wanted? They seem oriented more to stocks then authors/transcripts. 3) Heed @AndrewSayer advice about bind variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the relative size of your table or the number of records, but if you don't already have an index on the `author` column, you can try adding add one:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (author);
```

Comment: I don't think a missing index will cause the statement to run for more than 30 minutes. I would bet on a block by another session. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can *at least* try to suppress the idempotent updates, which can cause a lot of needless row-versions.

---

```
conn.cursor().execute("UPDATE table SET classification = '%s'
WHERE  classification <> '%s'
AND author = '%s'" % (sector_long, sector_long, ticker) )
```

---

Besides: since you are complaining about this update locking other processes, it could also be other processes [b]locking your update.